# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running

Tags: nvidia

I re-installed cuda_10.0.130_410.48_linux (which was working before). But I can't seem to find the drivers with nvidia-smi. Scratching my head here. I restarted as as well. Thanks in advance and any pointers would be helpful.

Then I installed nvidia-460.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:1sd0.0/0000:19:08.0/0000:1a:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v00sdsv00001458sd0000403Bbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
manual_install: True
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

lspci

```
lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family [1a03:2000] (rev 41) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])~$
```

dpkg

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-460:amd64                  460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-460                      460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-460:amd64               460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-460:i386                460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-container-tools                 1.3.1+ds-0lambda1                               amd64        Package for configuring containers with NVIDIA hardware (CLI tool)
ii  libnvidia-container1:amd64                1.3.1+ds-0lambda1                               amd64        Package for configuring containers with NVIDIA hardware (shared library)
ii  libnvidia-decode-460:amd64                460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-460:i386                 460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-460:amd64                460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-460:i386                 460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-460:amd64                 460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-extra-460:i386                  460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         i386         Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-460:amd64                  460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386                   460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-460:amd64                    460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-460:i386                     460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-460:amd64                  460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386                   460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460             460.39-0lambda0~18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Nvidia-settings

```
nvidia-settings
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help` for usage information.
```

[nvidia.com-smi-failed](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-16-04/48635) and [nvidia-smi-has-failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927199/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-ma) haven't helped.

Comment: Add information on HOW you installed the driver AND cuda. I would avoid mixing in anything else than those that are available via apt or possibly additional ppa:s. Note also that there appears to be some people having trouble with the 460-version of the drivers.

Comment: I managed to get this to work. Closing this.  Turns out the nvidia drivers weren't installed even though it said it was.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unllikely to go any further, i.e. end up as "useful".

Comment: agreed. I've voted to close it as well